# Adding keys to EC2 instance using terraform automation

Tags: bash, terraform, hashicorp-otto

I have automation on EC2 instance - loading different applications with credentials and keys.
I do not want to hardcode the keys - need a way to run automation with terraform.
What I thought doing so far:

1)create bash script locally and upload the script in terrafom using provisioner "file"

```
provisioner "file" {
source      = "keys.sh"
destination = "keys.sh"
```

** the bash script contains EXPORT to environment variables**

```
#!/bin/bash
#PLEASE ADD GOT .GITIGNORE


export REPO_SECRET=SoMeRepOSceRt

cat << EOF > /home/ubuntu/.ssh/privatekey
----KEY-RSA---STARS--HERE
AjsdhKKKSSL
--END--Key
EOF
```

The issue is that I can't source the file using "remote-exec inline source ./file" - getting error source not found.

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {

    inline = [
    "chmod +x /home/ubuntu/keys.sh",
    "source /home/ubuntu/keys.sh",
    ]
```

using (dot) . ./script not working also.

```
aws_instance.TestBashEnv (remote-exec): /tmp/terraform_1852118673.sh: 1: source: not found
```

So I need a way to source the file in automation when EC2 instaces is created so the env variables in the bash script will be applied.

**P.S - will be nice to have a fetature that checks if the bash file keys.sh is uploaded durring terraform apply setup (fileexists?)

Comment: Shouldn't running the script with `remote-exec` suffice your need? It should run the commands from the script and make the env var and private key available hence you don't need to use `source` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd go about this one.

```
provisioner "file" {
  source      = "keys.sh"
  destination = "/home/ubuntu/keys.sh"
}
```

followed by:

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
  inline = [
    "chmod +x /home/ubuntu/keys.sh",
    "/home/ubuntu/keys.sh",
  ]
}
```

This is explained in the Terraform documentation for [`remote-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) more thoroughly.

Comment: I have ```export REPO_SECRET=SoMeRepOSceRt``` in ```#!/bin/bash``` - I need to source it to set the env variable

Comment: Instead of running it as a regular shell script, try adding a . in front, i.e.: `. ./home/ubuntu/keys.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

The method I tried wont work.
Each bash script that wants to use keys need to source `keys.sh` at the start of the files.